# How to link boost to scons for compiling NVDA

Tags: boost, scons, nvda

I'm trying to compile and build [NVDA](http://community.nvda-project.org/) from source on Windows. The source code uses boost headers and uses scon for compilation. I have boost installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47`

scons gives the following error:

```
buffer.cpp
include\minhook\src\buffer.cpp(32) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/foreach.hpp': No such file or directory
scons: *** [nvdaHelper\build\x86\minHook\_minHook_buffer.cpp.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.`
```

Since `PATH` variable on my system contains the path to boost and scons couldn't find boost headers, I added `ENV` in the construction of `env` object in the sconstruct file.

```
env = Environment(variables=vars,tools=["textfile","gettext","t2t",keyCommandsDocTool,'doxygen'],ENV = {'PATH': os.environ['PATH']})
```

Printing `env['ENV']['PATH']` confirms that the path is added, but I still get the same error. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of how the compiler is invoked, and doesnt have anything to do with the PATH environment variable.

You need to setup what are called `Include Paths` as follows:

```
env = Environment() # construct the env accordingly
env.Append(CPPPATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47')
```

The CPPPATH is a [SCons Construction Variable](http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/a5025.html). Others that you will probably need are:

- LIBS - the libraries that need to be linked in to the binary
- LIBPATH - the paths to the libraries to be linked in
- CXXFLAGS - the compilation flags

Comment: Thanks. I had added CPPPATH and LIBPATH construction variables but I still see the same error.

Comment: @Siddharth, perhaps the path in CPPPATH is not correct, it depends on your installation. It may need to be "C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47\include". You should be able to concatenate the path in CPPPATH and path being included in your source into a valid path to the header file.

Comment: The line in the code causing the error is #include<'boost/foreach.hpp'>. The header file is present in "C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47\boost\foreach.hpp", so I guess the path in CPPPATH (C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_47) is correct. I've taken care of backslash too and highly doubt if it's a lexical mistake.

Comment: @Siddharth, can you show the compilation command that SCons executes to see what the compiler arguments look like. If its long, you can put it on pastebin.com

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/F0ZTwurZ) is the scons output. Original sconstruct file can be found [here](http://community.nvda-project.org/browser/sconstruct).

Comment: @Siddharth The only include path I see being passed to the compiler in the output is the following: "/Iinclude\minhook\include". Seems like the SCons code to add to the CPPPATH isnt being executed or something similar.

Comment: After adding 
`env.Append(CPPPATH = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/boost/boost_1_47')
print "CPPPATH is", env['CPPPATH']`
to the code, I see this output. Wonder why [this](http://pastebin.com/QxYiN59A) wouldn't be passed to the compiler.

Comment: @Siddharth, make sure your are compiling with the same env. Its possible to have multiple env's and you may be setting the CPPPATH on a different env than you are using to compile.

Comment: As per the documentation, the `env` variable on which I'm setting the CPPPATH is the [base environment](http://community.nvda-project.org/browser/sconstruct#L90) for the sconscript.